# Provide third party event trackers only using VAST

Tags: video, ads, vast

I am being ask to serve a VAST 2.0 tag which provides event trackers only.

So I have a regular VAST tag containing an ad (Creative) with no event trackers. Is there a way to add event trackers to this creative by serving another VAST tag?

If I serve a secondary VAST tag through a Wrapper (using VASTAdTagURI), I can provide a new ad with event trackers. But from what I understand from the documentation there is no way to link these event trackers to another creative (the one in the first tag). Or is there another way to provide my trackers through a second VAST tag, than using a Wrapper?

From my point of view it is not possible to achieve such a request but it seems to be a common request. What is the practice in the industry?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapper ads are designed for this purpose, but there is no way to link the trackers in a wrapper to one specific creative (in case a waterfall follows). If you cannot have your trackers inserted into the exact creative you want to track, the only other solution would be to add code into the player/parser. That way you could for example use an adid as trigger for your trackers.

Comment: Ok that is what I thought, thanks for your answer. Add code into the player could be a good alternative.